# Drupal Admin - unable to load

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I just tried installing a Drupal module and the installation was unsuccessful.
Trying to uninstall that module, however, now I'm not able to load the admin page because of the error message given from that failed module install.

How can I go over fixing that?

Also the module that I was trying to install is "devel_themer" and the error is

```
"Fatal error: Class 'simple_html_dom' not found in sites/all/modules/contrib/devel_themer/devel_themer.module on line 189"
```

Tried installing the "simple_html_dom" libraries under "sites/all/libraries/" but the error persist.

Thank you,
Tee

Comment: probably cache. go into database and empty all cache_* tables.

Answer (score 0):

Got it, I just downloaded and replaced the module with an older version and it works.